# How to Align Text when screen width is lower in responsive web design

Tags: html, css

When the width of the screen is lowered, the text is aligned to the center, however, only to an extent. The text is aligned to the center from the `min-width` of 616px, however, when the screen width is lowered below 615px, the text isn't aligned to the center anymore.

It looks like this:

[image]

How can I align the text to the centre even when the screen width is at this number and lower?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>MedConnect User | Home</title>
  <style media="screen">
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora&display=swap');

    body {
      background-color: #f8d4a4;
      font-family: Lora;
    }

    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    li {
      list-style: none;
    }

    .navbar {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-around;
      padding: 20px;
      margin-top: 50px;
    }

    .nav-links h3 {
      color: #704a1b;
    }

    .head {
      font-size: 32px;
      color: #614124;
      margin-top: -20px;
      margin-left: 50px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .menu {
      display: flex;
      gap: 1em;
      font-size: 18px;
      margin-left: 280px;
    }

    .menu li {
      padding: 5px 12px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .profile-btn {
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 1px black;
      padding: 10px 10px;
      margin-top: -10px;
      background-color: #60a159;
    }

    .profile-btn:active {
      box-shadow: none;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1201px) {
      .navbar {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 10px;
      }

      .navbar h1 {
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-size: 30px;
      }

      .menu {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-left: 10px;
      }

      .menu li {
        padding: 10px 20px;
      }
    }

    .index-first p {
      color: #614124;
      font-size: 40px;
    }

    .index-first h4 {
      color: #704a1b;
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    .index-first-text {
      margin: 130px 120px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      gap: 2em;
    }

    .consult-today-btn {
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 1px black;
      padding: 25px 25px;
      background-color: #60a159;
      width: 176px;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .consult-today-btn:active {
      box-shadow: none;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1201px) {
      .index-first-text {
        align-items: center;
        margin: 50px;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 790px) {
      .index-first-text p {
        font-size: 30px;
      }

      .index-first-text h4 {
        font-size: 15px;
      }
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar">
  <h1 class="head">MedConnect</h1>

  <ul class="nav-links">
    <div class="menu">
      <li><h3>Consult</h3></li>
      <li><h3>Resources</h3></li>
      <li><h3>About</h3></li>
      <li><h3>Contact</h3></li>
      <li><h3 class="profile-btn" style="color: white;">Your Profile</h3></li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="index-first">
  <div class="index-first-text">
    <p><b>Get Remote Medical Assistance here.</b></p>
    <h4>Find, Consult, Connect and Personalise your Needs Today.</h4>
    <h3 class="consult-today-btn" style="color: white;">Consult Today</h3>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The text is still centered, but it doesn't fit in your `.index-first-text` div anymore because of the 50px margin you've set. Try: `margin: 50px 10px;` instead in your `.index-first-text` class, and see if that helps. However, there will be a point where the text just won't fit. The next step is to center the text inside the `<p>` paragraph tag. It won't be pretty though. Have a further look at [text-wrap: balance;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-wrap), but support for that is currently poor. It will work in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code: `.index-first-text p { font-size: 30px; }` inside of the `@media screen and (max-width: 790px) {` block to include: `text-align: center;`

```css
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora&display=swap');

    body {
        background-color: #f8d4a4;
        font-family: Lora;
    }

    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    li {
        list-style: none;
    }

    .navbar {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-around;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    .nav-links h3 {
        color: #704a1b;
    }

    .head {
        font-size: 32px;
        color: #614124;
        margin-top: -20px;
        margin-left: 50px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .menu {
        display: flex;
        gap: 1em;
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-left: 280px;
    }

    .menu li {
        padding: 5px 12px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .profile-btn {
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px black;
        padding: 10px 10px;
        margin-top: -10px;
        background-color: #60a159;
    }

    .profile-btn:active {
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1201px) {
        .navbar {
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .navbar h1 {
            margin-top: 10px;
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        .menu {
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: center;
            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }

        .menu li {
            padding: 10px 20px;
        }
    }

    .index-first p {
        color: #614124;
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    .index-first h4 {
        color: #704a1b;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .index-first-text {
        margin: 130px 120px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 2em;
    }

    .consult-today-btn {
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px black;
        padding: 25px 25px;
        background-color: #60a159;
        width: 176px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .consult-today-btn:active {
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1201px) {
        .index-first-text {
            align-items: center;
            justify-items: center;
            margin: 50px;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 790px) {
        .index-first-text p {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        .index-first-text h4 {
            font-size: 15px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
        <h1 class="head">MedConnect</h1>

        <ul class="nav-links">
            <div class="menu">
                <li>
                    <h3>Consult</h3>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h3>Resources</h3>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h3>About</h3>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h3>Contact</h3>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h3 class="profile-btn" style="color: white;">Your Profile</h3>
                </li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="index-first">
        <div class="index-first-text">
            <p><b>Get Remote Medical Assistance here.</b></p>
            <h4>Find, Consult, Connect and Personalise your Needs Today.</h4>
            <h3 class="consult-today-btn" style="color: white;">Consult Today</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```